# Show that ¬p ∨ (r →¬q) and ¬p ∨¬q ∨¬r are equivalent.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic

I am new in Discrete Math so that I am still not familiar with Logical Equivalent rules.

1) Show that ¬p ∨ (r →¬q) and ¬p ∨¬q ∨¬r are equivalent.

My Try:

¬p ∨ (r →¬q)

$\equiv$  ¬p ∨ (¬r∨ q) [Laws of implication]

$\equiv$  ¬p ∨ (q ∨ ¬r) [Commutative laws]

$\equiv$  ¬p ∨ T        [Negation Laws]

$\equiv$  T [Domination Laws]

¬p ∨¬q ∨¬r

$\equiv$  ¬(p∧q∧r)

and I am just lost.

Comment: You went off the road at the first $\equiv$. Suddenly $\neg q$ turned into $q$. The fact is: $A\to B \equiv \neg A\lor B$. The step you explain with "[Negation Laws]" seems to suggest that (you think) $q\lor\neg r\equiv T$, i.e. that $q\lor\neg r$ is a valid formula. How could that possibly be? (Take $q$ false, $r$ true.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first step is wrong; by *material implication*:

> $¬p ∨ (r → ¬q) ≡ ¬p ∨ (¬r ∨ ¬q)$.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following:
\begin{align}
\neg p\lor(r\to\neg q)&\equiv \neg p\lor(\neg r\lor\neg q)\tag{material implication}\\[0.5em] 
&\equiv \neg p\lor(\neg q\lor\neg r)\tag{commutativity}\\[0.5em]
&\equiv \neg p\lor\neg q\lor\neg r.\tag{associativity}
\end{align}
As you can see, the above equivalence proof relies on the fact that you can use [material implication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_implication_%28rule_of_inference%29), commutativity, and associativity. If you are permitted to assume/use those without proving them, then the above should suffice.